# Canadian / Croatian travelling to India

Tags: india, tourist-visas, canadian-citizens, goa-india, croatian-citizens

I am meant to be travelling to India in December for a wedding. The Indian government is currently not issuing tourist visas to Canadians. I am a dual passport holder and will be travelling to / from India and applying for the visa with my Croatian passport. Is it possible that my visa will be denied because I have a Canadian passport?

Some people have suggested not putting that I have a Canadian passport, but the visa application asks if you hold another passport. I was also born in Canada and my Croatian passport was issued in Canada.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Hoping that another dual Canadian passport holder has already applied and been approved.

Thanks!

Comment: The only way to know is for you to apply for a evisa under your Croatian passport, being thruthful about the second passport you hold and seeing how it goes. I especiallty don't recommend waiting it out, December is around the corner. If the US ESTA is anything to go by, holding one eligible and one not eligible is enough to get you eligible for it.

Comment: Yes if I can get a reply from Karen, I may have an answer to my question. Thanks for the suggestion Nicolas - unfortunately hotels, flights, etc., are already booked (have been since before the VISA freeze) so hoping it works out okay